# Determine if type is a 'string' literal, 'number' literal or 'string | number' literal

Tags: typescript

Since the typescript now supports conditional types, I've decided to do some meta-programing to add more flavor to VSCODE intellisense. However, while other types are easy to separate using `A extends B` I have a hard time determining if the provided type is literal.

So the question would be - how do I determine if given type is of literal type?

Comment: Do you consider `"a" | "b"` to be of literal type?  What about `2 | string`?

Comment: I consider `"a" | "b"`, `1 | 2` and maybe `"a" | 1` to be of literal type. Any other union is invalid for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your use cases are.  Personally, I would do something like this:

```
type IfStringOrNumberLiteral<T, Y=true, N=false> =
  string extends T ? N : // must be narrower than string
  number extends T ? N : // must be narrower than number
  [T] extends [never] ? N : // must be wider than never
  [T] extends [string | number] ? Y : // must be narrower than string | number
  N
```

I always use [`--strictNullChecks`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#--strictnullchecks) so your mileage may vary when it comes to how that treats `null` and `undefined`.  Of course it can be amended to meet any particular need you have.  Mostly I just wanted to show an alternative to circuitous constructs of the form `( X extends Y ? true : false ) extends true ? U : V`.

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: This looks so clean! Thank you! Just curious, `[...]` are for cosmetic purpose only?

Comment: It's to prevent [distributing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) the conditional type over `T`.  Since `T` is what's called a "naked type parameter", the phrase `T extends string | number ? Y : N` could end up becoming `Y | N` if `T` is a union like `4 | object`, and I think you just want `N` in that case.  The way to prevent distributive conditional types it is to "clothe" the naked type parameter in some (covariant) way.  The tersest way to do that is the one-tuple bracket syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I've rewritten everything to match `jcalz's` clean style:

```
type IsStringLiteral<T> =
    string extends T ? false : // must be narrower than string
    [T] extends [never | undefined | null] ? false : // must be wider than never and nullable
    [T] extends [string] ? true : // must be wider than string
    false;

type IsNumberLiteral<T> =
    number extends T ? false : // must be narrower than number
    [T] extends [never | undefined | null] ? false : // must be wider than never and nullable
    [T] extends [number] ? true : // must be wider than number
    false;

type IsSingleTypeLiteral<T> =
    IsStringLiteral<T> extends false ?
    IsNumberLiteral<T> :
    true;

type IsLiteral<T> =
    string extends T ? false : // must be narrower than string
    number extends T ? false : // must be narrower than number
    [T] extends [never | undefined | null] ? false : // must be wider than never and nullable
    [T] extends [number | string] ? true : // must be wider than number | string
    false;
```

---

That was a little harder than anticipated, but after few hours I managed to achieve this:

```
type Switch<A, B, IF, ELSE = A> = A extends B ? IF : ELSE;
type IsStringLiteral<T> =
    // Check for nullable type using Switch type. See next comment why Switch must be used.
    Switch<T, undefined | null, true, false> extends true ? false : (
        // `T extends string` does not work for `"str" | number` and etc. Results in `boolean` type.
        // Need to use boolean Switch to filter out false-positive.
        Switch<T, string, true, false> extends true ? (
            // `string` does not extend literal type.
            string extends T ? false : true
        ) : false
    );
type IsNumberLiteral<T> =
    Switch<T, undefined | null, true, false> extends true ? false : (
        Switch<T, number, true, false> extends true ? (
            number extends T ? false : true
        ) : false
    );
type IsSingleTypeLiteral<T> =
    Switch<IsStringLiteral<T>, false, IsNumberLiteral<T>, true>;
type IsLiteral<T> =
    // `"string literal" | string` and etc. will return a false-positive `boolean` type.
    // `boolean` type must always be `false`, thus `false extends boolean` is used to get that `false` type.
    Switch<false, Switch<T, undefined | null, true, false> extends true ? false : (
        T extends string | number ? (
            string extends T ? false : (number extends T ? false : true)
        ) : false
    ), false, true>;
```

Here are some test cases in form of HTML table (tested with `3.1.1`):

```css
table, th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Test cases</th><th>IsStringLiteral</th><th>IsNumberLiteral</th><th>IsSingleTypeLiteral</th><th>IsLiteral</th></tr><tr><td>"string literal"</td><td><b>true</b></td><td>false</td><td><b>true</b></td><td><b>true</b></td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>false</td><td><b>true</b></td><td><b>true</b></td><td><b>true</b></td></tr><tr><td>string</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>object</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>[]</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>[string, number]</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>any</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>void</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>null</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>undefined</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>never</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>"string literal" | 123</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td><b>true</b></td></tr><tr><td>"string literal" | string</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr><tr><td>123 | number</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: "*...after few hours I managed to achieve this*" You asked the question 4 minutes ago and answered it the same minute?

Comment: @Johan When I'm playing Jeopardy! I go all the way :) https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Cheers, I was just really confused, didn't know about the format. Now I know I didn't travel in time :)