# How to determine if a TypesScript type is a literal

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write a utility type to determine if a type is a literal?
e.g.

```
type IsLiteral<T> ...

type IsStringALiteral = IsLiteral<string> // false
type IsStringLiteralALiteral = IsLiteral<'abc'> // true
type IsStringALiteral = IsLiteral<bool> // false
type IsStringLiteralALiteral = IsLiteral<false> // true
```

Comment: Interesting question! You can't really return a boolean value like that, but you could use the conditional types + `extends` and return `T` or `never`, something along those lines:

`type isLiteral<T> = T extends string ? T : never`

Comment: You can but rare it's to return true / false. Typescript is more indirect being precompile type checker so you'd more often do `Literal<T>=T extends string | number | boolean ? T : never;` so that this errors if you pass the wrong thing

Comment: @KrzysztofWoliński and Andrew - I'm fine with a different return type, but the challenge remains: how to implement the type logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, since I've figured it out:

```
type IsUnion<T, U extends T = T> = T extends unknown ? ([U] extends [T] ? false : true) : false;
type IsStringLiteral<A> = IsUnion<A> extends true ? false : A extends string ? (string extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsNumberLiteral<A> = IsUnion<A> extends true ? false : A extends number ? (number extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsBooleanLiteral<A> = IsUnion<A> extends true ? false : A extends boolean ? (boolean extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsLiteral<A> = IsStringLiteral<A> extends true ? true : IsNumberLiteral<A> extends true ? true : IsBooleanLiteral<A> extends true ? true : false;
```

Note here I have included IsUnion functionality because in my case I want:

```
type IsStringUnionALiteral = IsLiteral<'a' | 'b'> // false
```

If that doesn't suit your requirements, then it would be as follows:

```
type IsStringLiteral<A> = A extends string ? (string extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsNumberLiteral<A> = A extends number ? (number extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsBooleanLiteral<A> = A extends boolean ? (boolean extends A ? false : true) : false;
type IsLiteral<A> = IsStringLiteral<A> extends true ? true : IsNumberLiteral<A> extends true ? true : IsBooleanLiteral<A> extends true ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Determine if type is a 'string' literal, 'number' literal or 'string | number' literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806230/determine-if-type-is-a-string-literal-number-literal-or-string-number-l)

```
type IsString<T> = string extends T ? true : false;

type T = {
  true: true,
  123: 123,
  'text': 'text',
  string: string,
}
type X = {[K in keyof T]: IsString<T[K]>}
// type X = {
//     true: false;
//     123: false;
//     text: false;
//     string: true;
// }
```

Comment: That utility type is testing if it's a string. I want to test if it's a literal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works if you only want to check between string type and literal type:

```
type trueIfLiteral<T extends string> = string extends T ? false : true;
```

literal type is assignable to a string type, but a string type is not assignable to a literal type, that's why we have the constraint

```
T extends string
```

then we check if string is assignable to the type parameter.

```
string extends T ? false : true;
```

reference:
[Is it possible to get the value (not key) in a literal object as a literal, not its type (such as string) via mapped type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128598/is-it-possible-to-get-the-value-not-key-in-a-literal-object-as-a-literal-not)